# FB.Dialog.create is being deprecated. Is there an alternative?

Tags: facebook, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

As part of a facebook app we'll be prompting the user for input via a modal dialog.
Looking into this I came accross FB.Dialog.create() but when I used it I get the following message:

```
The method FB.Dialog.create is not officially supported by Facebook and access to it will soon be removed.
```

Is there another supported way to create custom dialogs, now or in the future?

Comment: No. Use window.alert, window.confirm or window.prompt if you’re happy with a very “basic” look – and if not, add some jQuery UI magic or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

I think FB.ui replaces FB.Dialog.